# How do contour plots work?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

So I'm trying to work out a way to make a contour plot where the contours label the percentage of enclosed data points say 75%, 50% and 25% of the total.

I've got a normalised gaussian kde from sklearn and I can plot the probability distribution function from the log density output.

To do what I want I either need to compute where the contours should lie prior to plotting them or plot a lot of contours close together and then find the closest (by some iterative technique which uses matplotlib's `path.contains_points()` maybe).

I would like to avoid using matplotlib to draw and redraw everything. So my question is: how does the contour algorithm work? I've looked at the source code but if someone has a good way of explaining it/how I could modify it would be very helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely a contour plot is to visual 3d data in 2d plots. You can subdivide the plane with the points and try a linear interpolation/transformation for the contours. So, basically you have 3 values x,y,z but you need to plot it in 2d. A simple contour plot is a triangulation of the points with the color of each triangle determined by the average value from the three vertices. Here is an example php implementation:https://cntm.codeplex.com/.

Comment: @Lucidnosense:If my answer is helpful please consider to accept and/or upvote it!